# Google Cloud App Engine Standard - Custom Domain Name with Subdomains

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl-certificate, subdomain, gcloud, custom-domain

I am struggling with the problem now for a couple of days. I hope someone can point out where I made the mistake.

I have a domain `mydomain.com`. (not purchased with Google.)

I have one AppEngine Standard Service (`default`) with my website.
Then I have 30 additional AppEngine Standard Services for my different api's (`service1-service30`).

1. When I browse to `mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com` I should be redirected to the `"default" service`.
2. When I browse to e.g., `service25.mydomain.com` I wanted to be redirected to the corresponding service. In this example `service "service25"`

---

What I did:

- [AppEngine Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaWNn.png)
- [DomainRegistrar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q18Xd.png)
- Dispatch.yaml:

```
  dispatch:
    - url: "mydomain.com/*"
      service: default
    - url: "www.mydomain.com/*"
      service: default
```

---

Calling `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` are working as expected with an valid SSL certificate.

- Calling `service25.mydomain.com` redirects to the `"default" service`
- Calling `service26.mydomain.com` returns `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`
- Calling `service27.mydomain.com` returns `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Regarding [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) and [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-routed) at least one of my previous methods should work and the default mapping/routing to the corresponding service name should be done.

If I add

```
- url: "service25.mydomain.com/*"
  service: service25
```

it works, but due to the `limitation of max 20 routes` in the [Dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml) file this is not working for me.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: At least the other domains are registered in the DNS? I think maybe not because of `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. For this error `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` the certificate seems not to be provisioned.

Comment: Just as a side note, sometimes takes a while to the domains to be matched to the services

Comment: Hi @FerreginaPelona, Thanks for your reply. As you stated, I don't have a CNAME entry at my DNS regristrar for `service27`. So `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` makes sense.
But I have an CNAME entry for `service26` pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com.` and still get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` even more than 12h later. Should the CNAME entry point to `mydomain.com`?
And why is `service25` redirected to the `default` service?
Thank you very much.

Comment: or do I need a wildcard certificate for my case?

Comment: Connection closed is a different error from NXDOMAIN. 1) You must map a custom domain to the service for each domain name. 2) You must have an SSL certificate containing the domain name or use a wildcard certificate.